# Can I add recent items view to Thunar Bookmarks?

Tags: xfce, thunar

In File select menu I can quickly find my most recent files.
Look at the top left corner.
[image: File select menu, Recent bookmark]
How I can choose with file open for editing.

Can I add that view to Thunar?
[image: Thunar view]

I know I can sort items in directory by access date. However, sometimes when I download files, I have no idea, where have I put them :D. So that view should pull most recent user-edited files from multiple directories.

Comment: If you don't know where you downloaded the files, how would you know what folder to include in Thunar? If you can narrow your downloading activity down to a specific tool, maybe we can guide you towards a solution.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I think the OP wants a virtual folder that incorporates the result of `find $HOME -type f -mmin -60`. It's quite a nice idea. I think I'd build it as a "real" folder of symlinks. Add new files via `inotifywait` and clean them out from a `cron` job.

Comment: Plausible, but if the files went to /tmp or /var/tmp or elsewhere, how do we know where to look? I'm hoping the OP can spell out a list for such a solution.

Comment: @roaima Tangentially related: Midnight Commander can do that (i.e. it can panelize a list of files produced by an arbitrary command).

Comment: Well, choose file dialogs (when I have to choose specific file to open/upload) have that virtual folder and they get it right. I have no idea, what do they use, so I cannot really give any pointers.

Comment: They include both recent downloads and recent modified files, so I find it convenient.

Answer (score 18):

1. Open ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks with your text editor.
2. Add this line at the end: `recent:/`
3. Save the file.
4. Open thunar. There should be a recent bookmark on the side panel now

Comment: Works! Now how do I get it to display the path as well?

Comment: Wow, witch craft! Thank you. This should be an option in Thunar i guess.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Any chance this can be sorted by date? Currently you would have to select date tab but this changes are Thunar-wide, affecting normal folders' view.